# Where to get Chinotto extract?

Tags: drinks, citrus, beverages, extracts

Chinotto drinks like San Pellegrino and Brio have Chinotto extract as their main ingredient.

Where can I get this extract? I've been looking around online, but cannot seem to find a supplier.

Answer (score 1):

I was also unable to find the extract, but I was able to find a site that allows you to purchase the chinotto sour orange tree!

Here you go: https://www.fourwindsgrowers.com/store/sour-orange-trees.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=30&category_id=8

Answer (score 1):

This ([Aromata Group](http://www.aromatagroup.net/en/settori-prodotti/bevande/estratti-tinture/)) is the closest I found, but unfortunately, it looks like it would be custom order industrial sized units for sale.

In this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DIY_eJuice/comments/32cnd2/chinotto_flavoring/), someone posted an untested mock Chinotto.

Some Google-ing showed allot of interest, but few consumer sources of Chinotto extract. Could be a business opportunity..?